# How do I make the class variable equal to my textbox value while converting to int32

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I get an error telling me that the value is not in the correct data type.

I have tried parsing and try parsing also.

```
namespace ScoreCalculator
{
    public partial class ScoreCalculator : Form
    {
        Int32 scoreTotal = 0;
        Int32 scoreCount = 0;
        public ScoreCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Int32 average;


            scoreCount +=1;
// the error vvvvvvv
            scoreTotal += Convert.ToInt32(scoreTotalTxt.Text);

            scoreTotalTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(scoreTotal);
            scoreCountTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(scoreCount);
            average = scoreTotal / scoreCount;
            averageTxt.Text = average.ToString();
            scoreTxt.Focus();
        }
}
```

It should let me make scoreTotal equal to the value in my scoreTotalTxt textbox plus its previous number.

Comment: The code you've shown works fine (or it fails with a `FormatException` if the textbox doesn't contain a valid integer). What is the specific exception message you're getting?

Comment: Hi @PaulB, welcome to SO. Please post the complete exception stack, not just the error message. Have you debugged this? What's the value of `scoreTotalTxt.Text` when you attempt to convert it?Perhaps you have a leading or trailing space somewhere? What's the initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32(scoreTotalTxt.Text);` Will fail with an error "input string not in a correct format" if you try and convert an empty string (nothing in your textbox) to a number

I suggest you check if the total box is empty, and set it to a value before you try and convert it:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(scoreTotalTxt.Text))
  scoreTotalTxt.Text = "0";
```

Comment: Thanks, it seemed impossible at the time and this was not actually the issue, but because of this I found that I was using score total instead of score as an add so the score total would never add the score to the total. So it was a assigning of incorrect variables and would have worked without this if statement. It is because of this statement that I can see my error. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to convert a string to an integer is to use the [`int.TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiX_sKxk8zkAhXLrJ4KHT3EBcIQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.int32.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw35Ul21c7qYu7DttNERjnwp) method, which takes in the string to convert and an `out` parameter that gets set to the value if the conversion is successful. It returns a `bool` that indicates success, so you can use it in an `if` condition.

Also note that you can call `ToString` instead of `Convert.ToString` on any `object`.

For example:

```
private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure we can convert our number first
    int additionalScoreTotal;  // This will hold the converted value

    if (int.TryParse(scoreTotalTxt.Text, out additionalScoreTotal))
    {
        scoreCount++;
        scoreTotal += additionalScoreTotal; // If we made it past the if, this has our value
        scoreTotalTxt.Text = scoreTotal.ToString();
        scoreCountTxt.Text = scoreCount.ToString();
        int average = scoreTotal / scoreCount;
        averageTxt.Text = average.ToString();
        scoreTxt.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The value in 'ScoreTotal' is not a valid integer");

        // Optionally, select the problematic text so they can change it
        scoreTotalTxt.Focus();
        scoreTotalTxt.SelectAll();
    }
}
```